# NotSupportedError : Calling QuerySet.exclude() after union() is not supported

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am getting the above error when I was trying to  exclude some datasets from the result..

```
votes = VoteResponse.objects.filter(project=self)
others = OtherResponse.objects.filter(project=self)
vote_responses =  votes.filter(date__year=self.date.year, date__quarter=self.date_quarter)
return vote_responses.union(others)
```

and I am trying to exclude the comments with null...

```
projectSnapshot.comments = projectSnapshotResponses.exclude(comments='').order_by('-date')[:10].values_list('comments', flat=True)
```

Could anyone please help me with this...

Thanks